# how to solve the issue about - server has not received a heartbeat from this host for more than 3 minutes

Tags: python, hadoop, certificate, ambari, hdp

we are using blue print in order to install ambari cluster ( masters machines + data node machines )

during blueprint installation we see that some machines in the cluster have lost the heartbeat , and from ambari we can see the following message

```
the server has not received a heartbeat from this host for more than 3 minutes
```

I search in google for slimier issue

but I only found the following

**one suggestion is**

update :

```
client.threadpool.size.max=<number of cores>
```

in the file -  /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties  ,and then restart the ambari server

**the second suggestion** is to disable the certificate as `verify=disable` , and then restart the ambari server

```
more /etc/python/cert-verification.cfg
# Possible values are:
# 'enable' to ensure HTTPS certificate verification is enabled by default
# 'disable' to ensure HTTPS certificate verification is disabled by default
# 'platform_default' to delegate the decision to the redistributor providing this particular Python version

# For more info refer to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0493/
[https]
verify=platform_default
```

I am not sure about the above suggestion or maybe someone here can bring the right solution